# Default image on Croppie

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to set the default photo when loading the croppie plugin for jquery.

```js
$(function() {
var basic = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
viewport: {
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  type: "circle"
}
});
basic.croppie('bind', {
  url: $('#default-foto').html() ,
  points: [77, 469, 280, 739]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.3.0/croppie.min.js"></script>

<div id='default-foto' class='hidden'>3314b70b13c1df9418fc2e81acc1490eb0fd1bfb.png</div>
<div id='upload-demo'></div>
```

I have no idea how close/far I am from the result.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the html(file url) out of the `DIV`

```
.croppie({
    url: $("#default-foto").html() ,
    ...
```

Comment: I edited the question because i found a typo. After applying your solution, still wont work. Any further ideas why?

Comment: can you try to duplicate your problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated my answer as well (Fixed the typo) plz try again

Comment: I updated my question and also made a JSfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/selenyum/o23hyjpe/

Comment: I've updated it a bit to make it work - https://jsfiddle.net/o23hyjpe/1/ please take a look